# Camel Spring Boot debug logging not working

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, logging, apache-camel

I'm unable to get Camel DSL to print DEBUG logs to the console under Spring Boot by setting the logging.level to the package name in application.properties:

`logging.level.org.test.logdemo=debug` <- doesn't print debug logs

If I set the LoggingLevel to INFO or WARN then the log prints:

```
.when(simple("${exchangeProperty.xmltestresult} == ''"))
  .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "2nd choice ID was empty")
  .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "2nd choice ID was empty")
  .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,"2nd choice ID was empty")
```

^ Both INFO and WARN print, DEBUG doesn't print.

If I specify a name for the route, and reference it in the application.properties file, then the DEBUG logs are printed:
`logging.level.FileRoute=debug`

```
from("file:///home/user/xmlfilein").routeId("FileRoute")
...
.when(simple("${exchangeProperty.xmltestresult} == ''"))
  .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"2nd choice ID was empty")
  .log(LoggingLevel.WARN,"2nd choice ID was empty")
  .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,"2nd choice was empty")
```

^ All of these logs are printed.

I've just started working with Camel Spring Boot, and I generated the project using Spring Initializr, which provided the following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>logdemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>logdemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Setting `logging.level.root=debug` works as well, and floods the console with debug messages, which I'm trying to avoid :)

Has anyone else experienced this and come up with a solution?  Is there something further up/down the chain that's overwriting the package=debug setting?

Is this a known bug with this version of Camel/Spring Boot?  Everything I've read to date states that this should work.

Comment: Read the documentation, see what the default logging name is when you use log eip in a Camel route: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/log-eip.html#_configuring_log_name_globally

You need to either set a route id or change the default logging name as shown in the documentatiopn

Comment: Thanks Claus!  I didn't realize I had to do that as well, I thought I just had to set the package name in application.properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
logging.level.org.test.logdemo=debug
```

This line will only print the logs, which are logged by the classes under `org.test.logdemo` package. It will not print apache camel logs which are not explicitly logged.

You can try with

```
logging.level.org.apache.camel=debug
```

It will print all logs under `org.apache.camel` package.

My suggestion will be first set `logging.level.root=debug`, then find out which class or packages are logging your desired information. Then change the
`org.apache.camel` to the package or or class name in `logging.level.org.apache.camel=debug`

For example, if the logs are printed by `RouteBuilder` class then the property should be

```
logging.level.org.apache.camel.builder=debug
```

Comment: I tried your advice Shawrup, but setting the logging.level.org.apache.camel=debug didn't work.  If I set it to logging.level.root=debug, then I see everything, but curiously the debug messages show as coming from 'route1'.  If I set the routeID, then that is what is listed as the source, it doesn't show me the class used.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the logs? Which logs you want to show ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a name in the log command :

```
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, **"myLog",** "2nd choice ID was empty")
```

and then in your application.properties :

```
logging.level.myLog=true
```